# Where is my "Address History" link disappeared?

Tags: issues

I used to have an "Address History" link that appeared when an address was updated in CiviCRM 5.10 probably (can't remember the exact version). I have logging turned on.

But since I have updated to the latest 5.13.5 that "Address History" link has disappeared. I have checked on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and it does not appear there too. Is it a bug or intentional removal? Is there a chance to get this back please, because it used to be a great feature I think. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I see reference to Address History in the GDPR extension: https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr so perhaps you saw it on a site that was using that